# JDBC + MySQL: Retry transaction in case of lockwait or deadlock

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ibatis, spring-transactions

I want any transaction that failed with "deadlock" or "lock wait timeout" to be retried 3 times.

I use SpringTransactionManager -> iBatis -> JDBC -> MySQL.

1) Can't I configure JDBC or MySQL ir IBatis to act that way?

2) What is the best place to add "wrapper" that will do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Spring AOP where if the target method throws an exception, you can point to the retry logic method. You would still have to code the retry method.